# support vector regression time series forecasting - python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, svm

I have a dataset of peak load for a year. Its a simple two column dataset with the date and load(kWh).

I want to train it on the first 9 months and then let it predict the next three months .  I can't get my head around how to implement SVR. I understand my 'y' would be predicted value in kWh but what about my X values?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your independent variables can be whatever you think is predictive of peak load. X could simply be the date, if you like. However it sounds like you need to do the upfront leg work to figure out what question you really want to ask. This decision, and your available data, guide what method/algorithm you use; not the other way around.

Comment: If, however, you are simply using this as an exercise to learn more about support vector regression (and you are capable of changing programming languages) I think this is a nice tutorial: https://rpubs.com/linkonabe/SLSvsSVR. I find the R packages for machine learning easier for beginners to implement than the Python versions. The latter often require writing more custom code.

Answer (score 0):

given multi-variable regression, y =

Regression is a multi-dimensional separation which can be hard to visualize in ones head since it is not 3D.

The better question might be, which  are consequential to the output value `y'.

Since you have the code to the loadavg in the kernel source, you can use the input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For Python (I suppose, the same way will be for R):

1. Collect the data in this way:
   [x_i-9, x_i-8, ..., x_i] vs [x_i+1, x_i+2, x_i+3]
2. First vector - your input vector. Second vector - your output vector (or value if you like). Use method fit from here, for example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.fit

You can try scaling, removing outliers, apply weights and so on. Play :)